# How to rewrite domain.com to www.domain.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to edit `apache2.conf` to rewrite domain.com to www.domain.com:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # if request is not for a file/directory 
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
    # then skip from rewrites
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    # add www to hostname
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
    RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # forward all the requests to `/index.php
    RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I can't see any obvious errors, but the rewrite doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a small one, the space between `^ http`. I mean idea?

Comment: Ok, then I am too stoopid, `.htacess` always gives me the shivers, because it is hard to debug if nothing works, and then everything just crashes without notice. But you have a simply "not redirecting, but everything else works"?

Answer (score 1):

Minor change in order of your rules:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add www to hostname
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} !=::1
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# if request is not for a file/directory 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
# then skip from rewrites
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# forward all the requests to `/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. Can you explain what the change was in practice/what was causing the error?

Comment: Sorry, actually this solution invalidates the escape for files not being rewritten?

Comment: Whether files or no files you still want to add www to all URLs right?